# php variable anomalous behaviour

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm trying to increment the value of the java script variable and php variable simultaneously , so in my java script i do :

```
<script>
<?php $i=1;?>
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
var abc = $('<input>').attr('name','demo'+i).attr('value','<?php echo set_value('demo'.$i++));
 <?php echo $i; ?>
 }
</script>
```

However ,every time the value of $i echo`ed is 2 , logically it should increment number of times the java script loop iterates and echo 5 but its not , what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: plz dont bother about the var abc = something something , i just want the 2 variables $i and i to have same value , which im not achieving

Comment: where is the closing php tag `?>` in `value`? did you miss typing it?

Comment: as i said dont bother with the syntax i just need a technique for achieve the simultaneous increment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP code doesn't run at the same time as the Javascript code.

The PHP code runs on the server, before the client receives the page. The Javascript code runs on the client, after the client has received the page.

You'll need to write a loop in your PHP code that provides the full data to your Javascript code.

One common way of doing it would to put it into an array and encode it as JSON serverside, then feed the JSON to your Javascript for further processing. Note, no extra parsing of the data is needed on the Javascript side, if you just assign it to a variable - JSON is valid Javascript.

#### Further reading

- [JSON in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)
- [JSON in Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: true , so there is not way i can increment the 2 variables together , like to have the same value ?

Comment: @user1537158: I've elaborated a bit on my answer. :)

Comment: sebastian Paaske 

how can i do this ?

 var demo = new array();
 demo = <?php (json_decode($error_structure,true)); ?> 
now access values from demo ?

Comment: `json_encode`, not `json_decode`. You want to produce JSON, not consume it. `var demo = <?php echo json_encode($error_structure); ?>;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop inside this code! (If you ask the PHP interpreter).

It is simply a PHP script which outputs a few lines of text (that happen to be Javascript code, which happens to contain a Javascript loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can try understanding this code:

```
<script>
    <?php
    echo "var data = [";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        echo "'".set_value('demo'.$i)."'";
    }
    echo "];";
    ?>

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var abc = $('<input>').attr('name', 'demo' + i).attr('value', data[i]);
    }
</script>
```

What actually happens is, once you run this php file, the php block generate output something like:

```
var data = ['demo1 value', 'demo2 value', 'demo3 value','demo4 value','demo5 value',];
```

this is an array in javascript, that you can use in the javascript code below the php block.

Comment: aah , uv misplaced the meaning of my question , i want to use set_value of php , how can i use the java script array within php ? 

    <? php set_value(data[i])?> not possible

anyways that trick was neat , thank you